# Page Layout arrangement

Tags: page-layout

weird minor "issue", more of an observation. I have two users who seemingly have the same setup (only the language differs). However, when they view the same record the way the fields and their values are arranged differ:

View 1: Value is next to the field name
[image]

View 2: Value is beneath the field name
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like both users have different `Display Density` setting . You can change these at `Clickpath`: View Profile(top right)> Display Density> Comfy/Compact

From [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.user_overview_lex.htm&type=5),

> Change the look of Lightning Experience by selecting your preferred combination of field label alignment and the amount of space between page elements. At the top of a Salesforce page, click your image. Then select a display density setting.

> Comfy is a spacious view with labels on the top of fields and more space between page elements.
> Compact is a denser view with labels to the left of fields and less space between page elements.

Comment: AHA! Thank you :)